# Python howto exception handle <urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize

My script in Python 2.7 scrapes a website every minute, but sometimes it gives the error:

urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>

How I can handle the exception? I am trying something like this:

```
from socket import error as SocketError
import errno

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
except SocketError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
        print "there is a time-out" 
    pass
        print "There is no time-out, continue"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the exception like this:

```
from socket import error as SocketError
import errno    

try:
    urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
except SocketError, e:
     errorcode = e[0]
     if errorcode!=errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        print "There is a time-out"
        # Not the error we are looking for, re-raise
        raise e
```

You can read [Error Code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html)

Comment: I have import your code into my script and after a half hour I receive the error: except SocketError, e: NameError: name 'SocketError' is not defined.

Comment: Add this line `from socket import error as SocketError` above `errno`.

Comment: I replaced except SocketError, e: in except socket.error as e: I will try this out if it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh I forgot your line of code! Ok I will try it again.

Comment: If still your problem not solved try this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851926/exception-for-connectionreseterror-errno-54-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: Grr I still get the same error, the link you send, that is for Python 3.0 I use python 2.7.

Comment: Take a Look [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163732/python-urllib2-connection-reset-by-peer) and [Documentation handle exception](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)